# map function causes infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, dictionary, redux

I have a list of wishlist products that contains ID of products. I want to  loop the list and show each product.
I did like this : 
Index.js:

```
 {this.state.wishlist.map( product => {
  return(
  <WishlistTable product={product}/>
   ) })}
```

Then  in WishlistTable i want to display label of each product. 
I did like this: 
In mapDispatchToProps:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
return {
  onFindById:  id => {
      dispatch(findProdById(id ));
  }
 }
};
```

FindProdById works well ,it gives all products which their id is the given id. 
In COmponentDidMount i dispatch my action :

```
componentDidMount(){
this.props.onFindById(this.props.product); 
}
```

then in render i have like this :

```
   <p> {this.props.products.label} </p>
```

It diplays only the label of the first product. 
i.e: for example if i have two products ; it diplays two labels which value is the first product's one.

Any help is considered.

Comment: This is weird. Why are you mapping your state, and then dispatching actions? You should never dispatch an action on a render: This is likely what is causing your infinite loop.

Comment: What does `findProdById` do? But as @FrankerZ said, dispatching your action likely triggers a re-render which will again dispatch and trigger a re-render and so forth.

Comment: @FrankerZ i'v updated my code. Please  take a look.

Comment: @trixn . findProdById  returns the products which id is the given one. I have updated the issue . Please take a look

Comment: Again `.onComponentDidMount()` is essentially your render. As soon as you dispatch it, your render function updates (Because your state has changed), and then triggers a re-render. The `.onComponentDidMount()` function will refire, and thus your loop starts again. The only place you should be dispatching actions, is from user actions, or from an external source.

Comment: @SihemHcine If you encounter a new and unrelated problem please ask a new question instead of modifying this one. Others with the same problem will not be able to find and understand that question anymore. Also the question body is not consistent with the title anymore.